# How to return some values from an asynchronous Task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm uploading a file using multipart data form and I need to keep the file description of the uploaded file. I'm using the following code

```
FileDescription temp = new FileDescription();
var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith<IEnumerable<FileDescription>>(t =>
{

    if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }

    var fileInfo = streamProvider.FileData.Select(i =>
    {
        var info = new FileInfo(i.LocalFileName);
        temp.AssociatedSchool = 1;
        temp.FileName = info.Name;
        temp.LocalFileName = i.LocalFileName;
        temp.FileSize = info.Length / 1024;
        temp.IsFileValid = true;
        temp.NoOfRecords = 1;
        temp.UploadedBy = 1;
        return temp;
    });
    return fileInfo;
});
```

This code doesnt set the values to the `temp` object. Can anyone tell me an alternate way to get the values? task.Result is always null. How can i get the values out of the thread?

Comment: `Select` is lazy linq function

Comment: where do you start or wait the task?

Comment: @Grundy , is there any replacement for Select?

Comment: what is a type of streamProvider? and it's FileData property

Comment: @potehin143 type is MultipartFormDataStreamProvider. I tried your answer, its not working. I need the value of file description used with the task for another variable. Is that possible?

Comment: It's strange that you trying to process collection (FileData) but use the same local var temp. What do you want to see in results? The collection if FileDescriptors? or single FileDescriptor for the First element of FileData?

Comment: First element of filedata

Comment: in your sample - it last element :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try change your sample like this

```
var descriptions = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider)
                          .ContinueWith<IEnumerable<FileDescription>>(t =>
            {
                if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                }

                var fileInfo = streamProvider.FileData.Select(i =>
                {
                    var info = new FileInfo(i.LocalFileName);
                    return new FileDescription(){
                        AssociatedSchool = 1;
                        FileName = info.Name;
                        LocalFileName = i.LocalFileName;
                        FileSize = info.Length / 1024;
                        IsFileValid = true;
                        NoOfRecords = 1;
                        UploadedBy = 1;
                    }
                });
                return fileInfo;
            }).Result;

var temp = descriptions.First();//Possibly you need FirstOrDefault
```